# Retrieving properties from Serilog LogContext

Tags: serilog

Is there a way to retrieve all the LogProperties that have been pushed into a current Context?  We have a separate system we push events to for Exceptions but would like to access all the properties that have been loaded up in to the LogProperties throughout the call chain.

I see that the TestCorrelator builds some mechanism to grab them, but the ability to view all the currently pushed LogProperties should be exposed somewhere right?  I just can't find it.

If not, is there a way we can intercept Log.Error and just use that code to push the exception to a third party service?

Comment: You can restrict the minimum level of events sent to a sink. And at that point you should have all the properties you need from the LogContext. What do you mean "separate system we push events to"? Did you create your own sink or use an existing one?

Comment: No, exception reporting to a third party service sits outside Serilog logging.  At the time we report the exception we would like to pull all the properties that have been gathered from the LogContext through the call chain so that we can send them to the exception management service.

Comment: You are literally describing the purpose of a [Serilog sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#sinks). Why don't you implement a sink to push the exceptions to this exception management service? You will have all the properties you need from the context at that point. [The interface is a single method](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Core/ILogEventSink.cs).

Comment: Mainly because the sinks dont pick up the proper call stack. I'm working on getting the Raygun sink integrated properly to fix that problem actually but haven't been successful yet.  Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean the sinks don't pick up the proper call stack?

Comment: Trying to build a sink to push log properties to my scoped service so they can be shared, but can not seem to get a scoped service injected properly into an event sink.  Has anyone had any success with this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that by writing your own sink, implement ILogEventSink. There you will get properties in the logevent object,  you can get the context property to match for your specific context call and all other properties which are pushed with the log.